# MySQL - Removing null value rows from table

Tags: mysql

I have a table **"user"** with over 60 columns. One of the column's name is **"username"**

I want to remove the rows where the **username** field is empty or **NULL**

How can I do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this

```
DELETE FROM user WHERE username IS NULL;
```

or

```
DELETE FROM user WHERE username = '';
```

[Problems with NULL Values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-with-null.html)

Answer (score 7):

If you want to delete all those rows containing username = NULL AND where username is  empty string ("") as well

then

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE username IS NULL OR username = '';
```

It is advised to first do a `SELECT` query with same `WHERE` condition as that you are going to use in DELETE query   to see which rows will be deleted:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE username IS  NULL OR username = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I have created a script for any kind of SQL table. please copy this stored procedure and create this on your Environment and run this stored procedure with your Table.

```
exec [dbo].[SP_RemoveNullValues] 'Your_Table_Name'
```

stored procedure

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
--akila liyanaarachchi
Create procedure [dbo].[SP_RemoveNullValues](@PTableName Varchar(50) ) as 
begin


DECLARE Cussor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT COLUMN_NAME,TABLE_NAME,DATA_TYPE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = @PTableName  

OPEN Cussor;

Declare @ColumnName Varchar(50)
Declare @TableName  Varchar(50)
Declare @DataType Varchar(50)
Declare @Flage  int 

FETCH NEXT FROM Cussor INTO @ColumnName,@TableName,@DataType
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

set @Flage=0


If(@DataType in('bigint','numeric','bit','smallint','decimal','smallmoney','int','tinyint','money','float','real'))
begin
set @Flage=1
end 
If(@DataType in('date','atetimeoffset','datetime2','smalldatetime','datetime','time'))
begin
set @Flage=2
end 
If(@DataType in('char','varchar','text','nchar','nvarchar','ntext'))
begin
set @Flage=3
end 

If(@DataType in('binary','varbinary'))
begin
set @Flage=4
end 



DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX) 

if  (@Flage in(1,4))
begin 

SET @SQL ='  update ['+@TableName+'] set ['+@ColumnName+']=0 where ['+@ColumnName+'] is null'
end 

if  (@Flage =3)
begin 

SET @SQL ='  update ['+@TableName+'] set ['+@ColumnName+'] = '''' where ['+@ColumnName+'] is null '
end 

if  (@Flage =2)
begin 

SET @SQL ='  update ['+@TableName+'] set ['+@ColumnName+'] ='+'''1901-01-01 00:00:00.000'''+' where ['+@ColumnName+'] is null '
end 


EXEC(@SQL)



FETCH NEXT FROM Cussor INTO @ColumnName,@TableName,@DataType
END

CLOSE Cussor
DEALLOCATE Cussor

END
```