# Can I remove blank user meta in wordpress?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Can I remove empty rows from wp_usermeta table?

```
SELECT * FROM `mw_usermeta` WHERE `meta_value` = ''
```

My database has 108920 blank rows in this table.

Comment: So you basically want to remove the rows whose value is `NULL` for meta_value coloumn?

Comment: `DELETE FROM mw_usermeta WHERE meta_value = ''` - but take backup before running this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql - Removing null value rows from table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22006909/mysql-removing-null-value-rows-from-table)